# Change of variables in gradient

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

Take two coordinates with $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r'$ and take a function $f(|\mathbf r - \mathbf{r'}|)$. In many electromagnetism derivations I see a conversion like this
$$
\nabla_r f(|\mathbf r - \mathbf{r'}|)= -\nabla_{r'} f(|\mathbf r - \mathbf{r'}|).
$$
I used $R=r-r'$ and by the chain rule
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} &=\frac{\partial r'}{\partial r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r'}\\
&= \frac{\partial }{\partial r'}.
\end{align*}
I do not get the $-ve$ sign. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$ are independent variables, so $\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}'}{\partial\mathbf{r}} = 0$.
This isn't a change of variables situation, it's about how $f$ depends on them.

Write $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'$. Then $f$ is a function of $\mathbf{R}$ only.
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{r}} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{R}}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{R}},
\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{r}'} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{R}}{\partial\mathbf{r}'} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{R}}.
$$
You can figure the rest out from here.